# Where can i see the google sheet in which app makers saves the data

Tags: google-app-maker

I am building an application using google app maker with google sheets as the back end. How can I access the google sheet that saves the data I intake using the application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

App Maker doesn't actually store the data in sheets, it stores it in a custom database associated with your app. The best way to view the contents of that database right now is to create a new page in your application and drag out a table widget to it. You can set the fields to editable as well if you want to allow editing.

Comment: Thank you very much, is the possible for a software like tableau to gain access to this data. Without exporting the data.

Comment: Not at the moment, you would have to export it. We do support using a Cloud SQL backend, however, which many tools support connecting to. You can also do a lot of charting and reporting from within App Maker, although it requires more coding than a tool which is built specifically for that.

Answer (score 1):

Just throwing it out there, but what I'm doing in one of my AppMaker apps is using a server Script to export to a sheet that I created.
Basically use the SheetsApp API to edit:
`sheet = SpreadSheetApp.openById(spreadsheetFileId).insertSheet(1);`

I create a new array newRow = [];

then I use a for-in loop to loop over the data in my app database and newRow.push, then use `sheet.appendRow(newRow);`

I then end up with a sheet that is a match to the data in my database.

Hope that helps.